# VBA Code runs properly but Run-time error '1004' still pops up

Tags: excel, vba

I'm learning VBA and I'm trying to create a workbook wherein in one sheet (sheet2) it would do the calculation then once the calculation is finished the items in sheet2, I would be able to press a commandbutton with the macro of copying the cells in the other sheet (sheet1). I am successful so far in copying over the data however every time the commandbutton is pressed, the error message

> 'Run-time error'1004': Application-defined or object-defined error'

would pop up. When the debug option is selected it points to line 4 & 5. I searched all over the internet regarding this issue and I haven't stumbled upon any situation like this. I've followed this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z62yORhPr3Q and it's 5th method I'm running with. The code that I have is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Part As Range
For Each Part In Range(Range("Q4"), Range("Q4").End(xlDown))
Sheets("VStock").Range(Part.Value).Value = _
Sheets("Calc").Range(Part.Offset(0, 1).Value).Value
Next Part
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: Probably `Part.Value` is not giving a valid range.

Comment: is VStock sheet1 and calc sheet2 or other way round?

Comment: Set ranges before the loop, you get error from `Sheets("VStock").Range(Part.Value).Value`
Simple way will look similar to:
`For Each cell In YourRange
    Range2.Value = YourRange.Value
Next cell`
P.S. you loop whole sheet column up to the very bottom, it may be very demanding task.
I would suggest simply use range1=range2.value without looping.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion not to loop the entire column and set the Ranges before the main task of "copy/paste".
In your case the ranges are set up incorrectly

```
Sheets("VStock").Range(Part.Value).Value = _
Sheets("Calc").Range(Part.Offset(0, 1).Value).Value
```

`.Range` should Look into the location of cells, example: `.Range("Q4:Q144").Value`
in your case, Range ends up with `.Range(*theValue*).Value`

Correct code Example:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheets("Calc")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("VStock")

Dim SourceRange, dbRange As Range
Dim lRow as Long

lRow = ws1.Range("Q" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If lRow <= 4 Then
    MsgBox ("No data to copy")
    Exit Sub
End If

Set SourceRange = ws1.Range("Q4:Q" & lRow) ' Calc
Set dbRange = ws2.Range("Q4:Q" & lRow) ' VStock

dbRange.Value = SourceRange.Offset(0, 1).Value

End Sub
```